# Genetic Algorithm Sudoku - optimizing mutation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I am in the process of writing a genetic algorithm to solve Sudoku puzzles and was hoping for some input. The algorithm solves puzzles occasionally (about 1 out of 10 times on the same puzzle with max 1,000,000 iterations) and I am trying to get a little input about mutation rates, repopulation, and splicing. Any input is greatly appreciated as this is brand new to me and I feel like I am not doing things 100% correct.

A quick overview of the algorithm

Fitness Function

Counts the number of unique values of numbers 1 through 9 in each column, row, and 3*3 sub box. Each of these unique values in the subsets are summed and divided by 9 resulting in a floating value between 0 and 1. The sum of these values is divided by 27 providing a total fitness value ranging between 0 and 1. 1 indicates a solved puzzle.

Population Size:
100

Selection:

Roulette Method. Each node is randomly selected where nodes containing higher fitness values have a slightly better chance of selection

Reproduction:
Two randomly selected chromosomes/boards swap a randomly selected subset (row, column, or 3*3 subsets) The selection of subset(which row, column, or box) is random. The resulting boards are introduced into population.

Reproduction Rate: 12% of population per cycle
There are six reproductions per iteration resulting in 12 new chromosomes per cycle of the algorithm.

Mutation: mutation occurs at a rate of 2 percent of population after 10 iterations of no improvement of highest fitness.
Listed below are the three mutation methods which have varying weights of selection probability.

1: Swap randomly selected numbers. The method selects two random numbers and swaps them throughout the board. This method seems to have the greatest impact on growth early in the algorithms growth pattern. 25% chance of selection

2: Introduce random changes: Randomly select two cells and change their values. This method seems to help keep the algorithm from converging. %65 chance of selection

3: count the number of each value in the board. A solved board contains a count of 9 of each number between 1 and 9. This method takes any number that occurs less than 9 times and randomly swaps it with a number that occurs more than 9 times. This seems to have a positive impact on the algorithm but only used sparingly. %10 chance of selection

My main question is at what rate should I apply the mutation method. It seems that as I increase mutation I have faster initial results. However as the result approaches a correct result, I think the higher rate of change is introducing too many bad chromosomes and genes into the population. However, with the lower rate of change the algorithm seems to converge too early.

One last question is whether there is a better approach to mutation.

Comment: I assume that there are certain values that are fixed and not subject to mutation? Another way of asking: is this problem designed to generate Sudoku puzzles or to solve a particular puzzle with fixed constraints?

Comment: It is designed to solve puzzles and yes I protect the initial cells. Thank You for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can anneal the mutation rate over time to get the sort of convergence behavior you're describing. But I actually think there are probably bigger gains to be had by modifying other parts of your algorithm.

Roulette wheel selection applies a very high degree of selection pressure in general. It tends to cause a pretty rapid loss of diversity fairly early in the process. Binary tournament selection is usually a better place to start experimenting. It's a more gradual form of pressure, and just as importantly, it's much better controlled.

With a less aggressive selection mechanism, you can afford to produce more offspring, since you don't have to worry about producing so many near-copies of the best one or two individuals. Rather than 12% of the population producing offspring (possible less because of repetition of parents in the mating pool), I'd go with 100%. You don't necessarily need to literally make sure every parent participates, but just generate the same number of offspring as you have parents.

Some form of mild elitism will probably then be helpful so that you don't lose good parents. Maybe keep the best 2-5 individuals from the parent population if they're better than the worst 2-5 offspring.

With elitism, you can use a bit higher mutation rate. All three of your operators seem useful. (Note that #3 is actually a form of local search embedded in your genetic algorithm. That's often a *huge* win in terms of performance. You could in fact extend #3 into a much more sophisticated method that looped until it couldn't figure out how to make any further improvements.)

I don't see an obvious better/worse set of weights for your three mutation operators. I think at that point, you're firmly within the realm of experimental parameter tuning. Another idea is to inject a bit of knowledge into the process and, for example, say that early on in the process, you choose between them randomly. Later, as the algorithm is converging, favor the mutation operators that you think are more likely to help finish "almost-solved" boards.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your input. It is going to take me a little while to try out these suggestions, I will reply back with my findings. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I once made a fairly competent Sudoku solver, using GA. Blogged about the details (including different representations and mutation) here:
http://fakeguido.blogspot.com/2010/05/solving-sudoku-with-genetic-algorithms.html

Comment: Yes, I looked at your blog quite extensively when trying to figure this thing out. It comes up on the first page of Google for 'Sudoku Genetic Algorithm'. It is a great help and is very much appreciated!

Comment: I wrote one post too here: http://anthony-tresontani.github.com/Python/2012/12/31/sudoku-generator-with-genetic/